# Dictionary Logic in Python class

Tags: python, dictionary

I was clear how dictionaries work in Python until I found this logic.

```
class Sample:
    __test = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__test
        self.key = "answer"
        self.count = "numbers"

    def print_test(self):
        print(self.__test)


s = Sample()

s.print_test()
```

In the above code a dictionary is initialized and then same variable is assigned to the class dict. In the next line  we are initializing 2 more variables to the class.

In the end we are initializing Sample class to an "s object"

As per my understanding this should be following output and __test dictionary should be empty

```
s.count = "numbers"
s.key = "answers"
```

But to my surprise the print_test functions returns

```
{'count': 'numbers', 'key': 'answer'}
```

Can anyone explain how the __test dictionary got these items as key value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__init__` function runs sequentially.  When you set `self.__dict__ = self.__test`, you assign the object's internal state dictionary to be empty.  However, when you next set the values of `self.key` and `self.count`, those attributes are added to the now empty `self.__dict__`, and by mutual assignment, to `self.__test`

You can see the difference you assign the empty dict at the end of the `__init__` method.

```
class Sample:
    __test = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.key = "answer"
        self.count = "numbers"
        self.__dict__ = self.__test

    def print_test(self):
        print(self.__test)


s = Sample()

s.print_test()
# prints:
{}
```

Comment: yes, i saw that

Comment: Are you still not sure what it happening?

Comment: I got it. Thanks